# ionic slide box not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i need to use a ionic slide box to show some images in my application. I used ionic slide box it does not seem to work with a ng-repeat.

this is my html part

```
<ion-view title="Promotions" ng-controller="PromotionsCtrl">


     <ion-content  class="has-header" scroll="true" padding="true">
        <ion-slide-box>

                <ion-slide ng-repeat="obj in promotions">
                        <img ng-src= {{obj.img}}> 

                </ion-slide>

         </ion-slide-box>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

my controller

```
.controller('PromotionsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate,$interval) {





            $http.get(  'http://******.com/B*****/service2.php?q=promotions', { cache: true})
            .then(function(res){

                  $scope.promotions = res.data['top'];


                  $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
                  });
                  })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use update() if you are using ng-repeat with slideboxes.

See here:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/%24ionicSlideBoxDelegate/

Comment: yes indeed,   $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update(); can be used after you fetch the data for ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

The newer version .rc4 of ionic updates the slide box on its own. Try updating your Ionic Lib.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to update the library please?

Comment: `npm install -g ionic` should do.

Comment: you'd have to change the version number in `bower.json` file, and running `bower install` again.

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample,the slide works,but when the delegate-handler updated,the parameter of the "does-contunue" can't work,I'm Still looking for a solution...

html:

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" does-continue="true" auto-play="true" delegate-handle="image-viewer" style="height:30%;">
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="slide in slideList">
            <div class="box" style="background-image: url('{{slide.url}}');background-size:100% 100%;></div>
    </ion-slide-box>
```

controller:

```
angular.module("myApp.controllers", ["myApp.services"])
.controller("myController", function ($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, myService,$timeout) {
    $timeout(function(){
        var slideList = myService.getSlides();
        $scope.slideList = slideList;
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('image-viewer').update();
    },2000)
})
```

service:

```
angular.module("myApp.services", [])
.factory("myService", function () {
    return{
        getSlides: function () {
            var slideList = new Array();
            slideList.push("imgs/a.jpg");
            slideList.push("imgs/b.jpg");
            slideList.push("imgs/c.jpg");
            return slideList;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Karan said, the `update` is call by itself. But there is still some problems. As mentioned in the [issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4309), you can disable the slider if the data is not ready. Then everything will be fine.